# What is the maximum video/movie resolution for iPad 3 (retina)?

Tags: ios, ipad, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, retina-display

For some reason, when I try to play a video that is 1536x2048 on the ipad 3, it doesn't play the video, it just skips it.  I've checked that the URL for the video is correct.  I'm using MPMoviePlayerController.  I tried playing the same video on an ipad also and it does the same thing.  It just acts like it ignored the "play" line of code.

Is there a maximum supported video resolution then?

Comment: This might answer your question:

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44440/can-ipad-3-play-20481536-video-in-its-native-resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`MPMoviePlayerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) reference I'd say that this can answer you:

**Supported Formats**

This class plays any movie or audio file supported in iOS. This includes both streamed content and fixed-length files. For movie files, this typically means files with the extensions .mov, .mp4, .mpv, and .3gp and using one of the following compression standards:

- H.264 Baseline Profile Level 3.0 video, up to 640 x 480 at 30 fps. (The Baseline profile does not support B frames.)
- MPEG-4 Part 2 video (Simple Profile)

If you use this class to play audio files, it displays a white screen with a QuickTime logo while the audio plays. For audio files, this class supports AAC-LC audio at up to 48 kHz, and MP3 (MPEG-1 Audio Layer 3) up to 48 kHz, stereo audio.

Comment: I saw that, but it didn't make sense that 640x480 was the max, since 768x1024 plays fine on iPad.

Comment: in MP4 part 2 or in MP4 part10 / H264? Cause the maximum allowed resolution for part 2 is full hd (1920x1080)